# Google Play SDK not in SDK Manager

Tags: android, google-play

I need to download the Google Play SDK (for the maps) but for somre reason it does not appear in the SDK download list.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What version of the Android SDK tools do you have installed?

Answer (score 0):

In the SDK Manager go to tools menu and then to options. Then check the box where its written Force https://......
Now extras list will be shown completely.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue... and the answer above "force https" solved the issue!